# When using JSESSIONID in the URL, a new session is created

Tags: java, session, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I make the following request:

```
http://qwerty.localhost:82/Server/chat/connect;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=05493D28DDD97308D66DAAC3DD66EAC2
```

or so:

```
http://qwerty.localhost:82/Server/chat/connect/;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=05493D28DDD97308D66DAAC3DD66EAC2
```

In this case, the session id (8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR) is passed both in cookies and in url (So it is necessary for the forest of safety, suddenly the cook will not be delivered). For some reason, a new session is being created. Why is this happening? what is wrong doing? can url not that ...

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I don't see JSESSIONID in url

Comment: @user1516873 JSESSIONID = 8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR (I set in `web.xml`)

Comment: So why you didn't wrote it in question? Please add configuration and short example with steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @user1516873 And what's that?
 `In this case, the session id (8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR) `. I update header.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a  new session is created for each request then, that means the client has cookies disabled and the URL-rewriting is not working properly.
If you do encode your URLs, the Container will first attempt to use cookies for session management, and fall back to URL rewriting only if the cookie approach fails.

Try this way :
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);//Passing “false” means the method returns a pre-existing session, or null if there was no session associated with this client.

and for URL Rewriting, use response.encodeURL()

Comment: where this use?

Comment: in the servlet, where you are sending the request and written code for creating a session.

Comment: tomcat8 create session. not i. I not write code for create session.

Comment: can you write example please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as example and proof of concept i created worked sample

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.company.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet

```
package org.company;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        resp.getWriter().printf(session.getId()+ " isNew:" + session.isNew());
    }
}
```

build script:

```
group 'org.company'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

war{
    archiveName = 'ROOT.war'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
}
```

After deploy war in tomcat:

request page without cookie

```
GET http://localhost:8080/
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

response:

```
Content-Length: 48
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 12:32:08 GMT
Set-Cookie: 8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=AD5F8B47BB0CEC1A08D8887FB82384BD.tc00;path=/;HttpOnly
```

page show AD5F8B47BB0CEC1A08D8887FB82384BD.tc00 isNew:true

if you open new browser ( or go to incognito mode ) and request page with cookie:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=AD5F8B47BB0CEC1A08D8887FB82384BD.tc00
```

you will get in return

```
AD5F8B47BB0CEC1A08D8887FB82384BD.tc00 isNew:false
```

headers

```
Content-Length: 49
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 12:37:38 GMT
```

but if you change that value, for example

```
GET http://localhost:8080/;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=AD5F8B47BB0CEC1A08D8887FB82384BD.tc01
```

than you will get new session 2061CBA151CE2148687B2BF48807253F.tc00 isNew:true
and server will return set-cookie header

```
Content-Length: 48
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 12:38:42 GMT
Set-Cookie: 8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=2061CBA151CE2148687B2BF48807253F.tc00;path=/;HttpOnly
```

Everything is work as expected, so problem related to different part of your programm.